# How can I change data in a VBO?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, buffer, lwjgl

I am attempting to use the `glMapData()` and `glBufferSubData()` methods to modify an existing VBO.

My current code is the following:

```
public void updateBufferData(int vaoID, int vboID, long index, int value){
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID); //bind VAO
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID); //bind VBO
    IntBuffer buffer = storeDataInIntBuffer(new int[]{value}); //I'm not sure if I should do it like this?
    GL15.glBufferSubData(vboID, index, buffer); //set data
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); //unbind VBO
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0); //unbind VAO
}
```

However when I call this method, it doesn't seem to have any effect on the VBO. The rendered object is still the same.

I'm pretty sure that the VBO/VAO aren't bound to anything else when the `updateBufferData()` method is called.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this question, but it's fairly specialized. I tried to do this myself a while back, and failed. I'll bounty this question if nobody answers it to try and give it some more attention. Also, could you be a bit more clear (with screenshots if possible) as to what the *actual* behaviour is, and what the *expected* behaviour is?

Comment: I have edited your question to the best of my ability given the current information. If anything is wrong, feel free to edit it. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8820876

Comment: @Joehot200 Nice edit, thank you. Also great comments.

Comment: The first parameter for `glBufferSubData` should be `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` not the vbo ID.

Comment: @Alex Yes, that works like a dream. Thank you very much.

Comment: @nautilus_rs I'd appreciate it if you could accept an answer so I can apply the bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, two things here:

First off, you don't need to bind a VAO to update an VBO. Once you've specified that said VBO is the source for the `glVertexAttribArrayPointer` (you do this when you create the VAO) you don't need to bind them together anymore. For drawing you bind the VAO, for VBO modifications you bind the VBO. Think of it this way: the same VBO may have been bind to several VAOs, so there's no sense in binding a specific VAO to update it.

Now on to the actual answer, you're doing the `glBufferSubData` call wrong. It should be using `GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` as the first parameter, not the VBO ID, since that has already been bind to the `GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding point.

Comment: I've decided to bounty this answer, since it had the most upvotes (and it would have got the bounty automatically anyway). Enjoy the rep! :)

Answer (score 1):

In my android projects with opengl es 2.0 i use the following code:

```
...
buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexCount * vertexDimension * BYTES_PER_FLOAT).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
...
// Bind to the buffer. Future commands will affect this buffer specifically.
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bindingId);

// Transfer data from client memory to the buffer.
GLES20.glBufferSubData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, buffer.capacity() * BYTES_PER_FLOAT, buffer);

// IMPORTANT: Unbind from the buffer when we're done with it.
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Code is not complete, but i think it is quite clear. As you can see, the first parameter of **bindBuffer** and **bufferSubData** is always **GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER**.

I don't alloc a new byte buffer every time i have to modify VBO. Simply i update native buffer with the following code

```
buffer.put(coords, 0, size).position(0);
```

and then i use the buffersubdata specifing the data range i want to update.